# Laravel / Vuejs Linked Share

Tags: jquery, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I want to share my current page (If laravel) or share post (if VUE js). I have added the `og` tags in head. Image and title is getting shared but description not.
Is there anything which i need to add to share description.

Following is my Head tag code

```
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:title" content="B1G1: Business for Good" />
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:description" content="0 school meals to children in need in India were given." />
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:type" content="Test" />
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:image" content="https://api.b1g1.com/uploads/projects/10/1436419809_proj_sq_10.jpg" />
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:url" content="http://127.0.0.1:8000/testing" />
```

And Share link is like

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url={{url}}','_blank', 'width=600, height=600'); return false;">Share</button>
```

Did i missed anything?

I have added the current format of Share page.[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have not stated what the issue that you are having is.

Comment: Hi Josh. My issue is, i want to share the description too which is not getting display when i open share screen

Answer (score 0):

Change your button code to below (change out the variables as needed) and you can send the comment also

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url={{url}}&summary={{description}}&title={{title}}','_blank', 'width=600, height=600'); return false;">Share</button
```

for more details about the information that you can send

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin and go to "Customised URL"

Hope that helps

Comment: OK a couple of things. Make sure your variables and url-encoded and add this to the end `&mini=1`